# Interest Only using TimeValue and Annuity

Tags: finance

I'm wondering if there is a way to calculate the interest only payment on a mortgage using the `TimeValue[]` and `Annuity[]` functions.   The Interest only payment is usually the first compounded period's interest. I'm not sure how that works out for scenarios where the Annuity is compounded at different intervals than payments are made. I can do this using my own calculations. I'm more interested in knowing the Mathematica functions for achieving the same thing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one function using `TimeValue` and `Annuity` built in functions that can be used to compute the amortization table. It takes four arguments (loan amount (pv), loan term in years (years), annual percentage interest rate (APR) and frequency is 1 for annual payment and 12 for monthly payment) and produces amortization table:

```
amortizationTable[pv_, years_, APR_, frequency_, fv_: 0] := 
 Module[{nper, rate, payment, balance, amortable, interest, 
   principal, 
   head = {"Period", "Beginning Balance", "Payment", 
     "Interest Payment", "Principal Payment", "Ending Balance"}},
  nper = years*frequency;
  rate = APR/frequency;
  payment = Abs[(pv + (pv + fv)/((1 + rate)^nper - 1))*(-rate)];
  balance = TimeValue[Annuity[payment, nper], rate, 0];
  amortable = Table[
    interest = balance*rate;
    principal = payment - balance*rate;
    balance = balance - principal;
    {month, balance + principal, payment, interest, principal, 
     balance}, {month, 1, nper}];
  Grid[Prepend[amortable // Round, head], Dividers -> All]]
```

For example:

```
amortizationTable[40000, 1, 0.05, 12]
```

[image]